# How to write regex for the following case?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ValuatePropertyRequest;
use App\Valuation\ValuationManager;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class SomeController extends Controller
```

I want to select all the `use` lines

`use [A-Za-z\\\n;]*` This is what I came up with, with my limited knowledge.

This selects:

[image]

But I want to select from first `use` to last `use`'s `;`

What would be the correct regex for this?

Comment: Try [`/^use .*(?:\r?\nuse .*)*/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/BeNli1/1). Or, just [`/^use .*/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/BeNli1/2). What is the programming language you are implementing it in? PHP? JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have `\n` in the character set. So it matches the newline and any characters at the beginning of the next line that are in the set as well.

Just take `\n` out of the regexp.

```
use [A-Za-z\\;]*
```

You probably also want to end the match at the `;` character, rather than allow multiple of them in the match. So it should be:

```
use [A-Za-z\\]*;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to select lines which starts wuth 'use'.
So, following regex's will help you with this:

```
use.*
```

or

```
use.*;
```

Hope I answered your question.